# SSL on Nginx causes redirect loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ssl, nginx, https

I'm trying to setup SSL on a Digital Ocean VPS using Nginx. My server conf is like so:

```
upstream unicorn {


server unix:/home/ubuntu/apps/example/shared/sock/unicorn.example.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  www.example.com example.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443;

  include example_ssl;

  server_name www.example.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  include example_ssl;

  server_name example.com;

  root /home/ubuntu/apps/example/current/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    #add_header Last-Modified "";
    #add_header ETag "";
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 60;
}
```

The ssl info is in example_ssl:

```
ssl on;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

ssl_session_timeout  10m;

ssl_ciphers "AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
```

This is causing an endless redirect loop. Http requests are redirected to HTTPS as expected but all tries to https://example.com are being redirected back to HTTP.

I can't seem to figure out why the HTTPS requests are being redirected. I checked my SSL cert by going to www.digicert.com and everything came back saying it was successfully installed.

When I try from my terminal:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
```

I get the following error:

```
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

The cert I got from my client did not contain the intermediate certs, but from what I understand this should still work when trying to access the site from the browser.

If I change the server block to only listen for 80 and not use SSL the site is able to load successfully, but I need to use SSL only.

Also, this is hosting a Rails app with Unicorn web server. My unicorn.log is empty other than starting the webserver so am I correct that this is not touching my Rails configuration at all, just an issue with nginx/ssl cert configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have two server blocks listening on 443, and the first one is doing a rewrite of the URL?  Remove the first 443 server block.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
upstream unicorn {
server unix:/home/ubuntu/apps/example/shared/sock/unicorn.example.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  include example_ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  root /home/ubuntu/apps/example/current/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    #add_header Last-Modified "";
    #add_header ETag "";
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 60;
}
```

You will need to remove "ssl on;" from your ssl include file, that is for older versions of nginx. You might have to modify this if you are using multiple ssl on a single IP.

Comment: I was missing `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`. Thanks!